# Google geocoding inaccuracy (in Israel)

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

I'm trying to use Google Geocoding API, but i keep on getting a very inaccurate answer (off by 3.2 KM).

Here is an example:
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&address=Hava%27ad+Haleumi+21+Jerusalem

I get the coordinate 31.7857,35.2007.

Ff you look up "Hava'ad Haleumi 21 Jerusalem" in maps.google.com, you can see that the location is 3.2KM away from what Google Geocoding API gave me.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Thank you.

Comment: @SRM that looks like an answer.

Comment: @yc Good point.  I moved it to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the Google Maps API does not support geocoding in Israel beyond city level, so your solution is to do what you did and finding an alternate geocoding service.

The reason you got the correct location when searching on maps.google.com is because the API uses a different provider than maps.google.com due to licensing issues.

Here is a [spreadsheet detailing the coverage area for Google Maps](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapcoverage_filtered.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use waze.co.il instead of google:

Their JSON API is

> http://www.waze.co.il/WAS/mozi?q=yourAddress&token=yourToken

(Also, as stated in this thread http://www.waze.co.il/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=6113
reverse geocoding is a paid service.)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the response. You are getting a partial match and the location type is approximate. If you look at the veiwport you will probably find that the location you are looking for falls within that viewport. *Edit - Actually it looks like it just matched to city - Jersulem in this case - which is why you are probably off by so far

Comment: But why does it do that? if i look up the exact same query on google maps, i get the right location. any location i search for inside Jerusalem, i get a location far off.

Comment: Something strange is definitely going on here.  When I type the address you specified in google maps, it indeeds locates the marker in the correct place.  When I use the address as an argument to the api it returns the match you saw.  One thing to note, after typing in the address using latin characters the address is redisplayed by google using hebrew.  I'm not sure if that makes a difference or if you could even submit a request using hebrew, but google is definitely confused.